# Mapping between Hex range and decimal range

Tags: c#, .net, hex, sony

I'm trying to create a simple interface where if a user types any number in the range of -170 to +170, then it converts the number into the hex range that Sony have described in their manual [here](https://www.sony.net/Products/CameraSystem/CA/BRC_X400_SRG_X400/Technical_Document/E042100111.pdf) (pictures below).

In the manual, sony have put the range as -170 = DE00 and +170 = 2200.

I've had a try of thinking of a logical mapping between the values but can't think of anything, does anybody know what the correct method of mapping between the above hex and the decimal ranges should be?

[image: Absolute reference]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Pan appears to be +- 0x2200 expressed as a signed 16 bit integer.  That suggests to me that the range is 0x2200 = 8704, so 170/8704 is about 0.02 degrees per increment.  Similarly, the Title (Image Flip Off) would be 90/4608 or the same 0.02 degrees per increment.